# Could you recommend some resource to train solving of examples?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, self-learning

I need some resource or book to train in solving of examples from pre-calculus, calculus 1 and some discrete math.But there should be full answers, step by step solution.Cuz my biggest problem in math is to choose the right way solving of the task.

Comment: Schaum's Outlines.

Answer (score 0):

The only book I know that meet your need is Inside Interesting Integral which consists a lot of integrals and techniques to solve them.